# React Native Socketio-client (Chat App) displaying one message many times H-E-L-P

Tags: android, react-native, server, socket.io, expo

First of all, thank you for taking the time to read this.
I'm making a chat app in react native(expo), and I'm using Socket.IO client & server to send and receive messages.
The App is being run on Android Emulator, and the server is running on a second Computer a few inches away from me. Both are connected to the same internet.
(running 2 android emulator devices to test)
I am successfully receiving and sending the messages, but there is a huge problem. Each time I send a message from one device, it shows the same message multiple times on the other device.
[THE RECIEVING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVWvP.png)
[THE SENDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPbLh.png)
Here if the Component:

```
import React,{useState, useLayoutEffect} from "react"
import { View,Text,Dimensions, TextInput,FlatList, Image, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, 
         Keyboard} from "react-native"
import { authx} from '../db/firebase';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window")

const socket = io("http://192.168.1.5:3000")   //IO CONNECTING!


export default function DebateScreen3(x) {
     const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
     const [oMsg, setOMsg] = useState()

   

   //SOCKET-IO CLIENT CODE: (Maybe Problem Lies here?)
  
    socket.on("connect",()=>{
      console.log(socket.id)
    })

    socket.on("receiveMessage", (msg)=>{
       console.warn(msg);
        setMessages(oldMessage=>[...oldMessage,msg])
     })

    useLayoutEffect(()=>{
       socket.emit("joinRoom",x.route.params.dbCollectionChat)
    })

    const sendMessage = () => {
       const messageTO = {
                     text:oMsg,
                      email:authx.currentUser.email,
                     user:authx.currentUser.displayName,
                     avatar:authx.currentUser.photoURL,
                     createdAt:  ~~(+new Date() / 1000),
                      }
        setMessages(oldMessage=>[...oldMessage,messageTO])
        socket.emit("sentMessage",messageTO,x.route.params.dbCollectionChat) 
        setOMsg("")       
       }

      //CLIENT CODE ENDS HERE


    if(false){
      return(
         <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"white", alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center"}}>
               <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
        </View>
    )
} else {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <FlatList 
                data={messages}
                inverted={false}
                extraData={messages}
                renderItem={({item}) => {
                    return ( <GetS 
                                text={item.text} 
                                user={item.user}
                                email={item.email}
                                avatar={item.avatar}
                            />)
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => { return(index)}}
            />
            <View style={{marginBottom:20, paddingHorizontal:20, flexDirection:"row", marginTop:10}}> 
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"
                    value={oMsg}
                    style={{borderColor:"grey",borderWidth:1, height:40, width:width/1.4, borderRadius:27, paddingHorizontal:10}}
                    value={oMsg}
                    onChangeText={(x)=>{setOMsg(x)}}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={{width:width/6,backgroundColor:"yellow",borderRadius:20, marginLeft:10, justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}} onPress={sendMessage} >
                        <AntDesign name="arrowright" size={24} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}


//Chat
function GetS(x) {
    if(x.email == authx.currentUser.email){
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, marginVertical:10}} >
                 <View style={{alignItems:"flex-end", marginRight:width/27}}>
                     <Text style={{backgroundColor:"lightblue", paddingHorizontal:width/24, paddingVertical:height/50, borderRadius:26}} >{x.text}</Text>
                 </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
    else {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1, marginVertical:10}} >
                <View style={{marginLeft:7, justifyContent:"flex-start", flexDirection:"row",alignItems:"center"}}>
                    <Image source={{uri:x.avatar}} style={{height:20,width:20,borderRadius:50}} />
                    <View style={{backgroundColor:"yellow", paddingHorizontal:width/24, paddingVertical:height/50, borderRadius:26, marginLeft:5}} >
                        <Text>{x.text}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize:10,fontStyle:"italic", marginTop:2}} >{x.user}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

}
```

Here is the Code for the Server:
(I also save the chat in DataBase, but that code is commented since i wanted to look into the problem. The problem (of messages repeating) occurs both with the DB-Code and without it.)

```
 const connect = require("./db/connect")
 const ChatSchema = require("./db/chatSchema")
 const mongoose = require("mongoose")
 const io = require("socket.io")(3000)

 io.on("connection",socket=> {

 console.log("Connected!")
 console.log(socket.id)

 socket.on("sentMessage",async(message,chatId)=>{
     try {
         console.log(message)
         socket.join(chatId)
         socket.to(chatId).emit("receiveMessage",message)
         // const Chat = new mongoose.model(chatId,ChatSchema)
         // const chat = new Chat(message)
         // await chat.save()
         // console.log("Saved succesfully")
      }
      catch(e){
        console.warn(e)
      }
 })

  socket.on("joinRoom", (roomId)=>{
     console.log("Joining:"+roomId)
     socket.join(roomId)
  })
})
```

I dont know why the problem is occuring!
Maybe React Native component Rerenders everytime a message is recieved/sent, which causes the Socket.IO make a new socket-connection with the server? Maybe the old socket-connection is not disconnected which causes the Client/App to recieve the message from both Socket-Connections and give me shows me both repeated messages.
Maybe theres a flaw in my React Native/Flatlist code?

Comment: Check your join room logic maybe that is calling multiple times.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Yess Thank You / JazakAllah !! That solved the issue :D.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed I just have one more question regarding this. You can see I connect to the socket io server inside the component, so when the component rerenders the client has to reconnect. I can not find a way to get the connection part out of the component! Do you have any suggestions?